# dotCMIS Authentication with Ticket

Tags: authentication, alfresco, cmis, dotcmis

dotCMIS supports both Basic and NTLM authentication.
I am currently using dotCMIS to connect to Alfresco using Basic Authentication.

I'd like to authenticate once with user/password for the sessions and then use Alfresco tickets, rather than pass user/password information for each request.

I think that Chemistry dotCMIS does not support authentication using tickets.
What would be the best way to add this capability?
Maybe with a custom authenticator?  It would need to track, recover and get a new ticket reissued after a session timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implement a new authentication provider for this. It shouldn't be difficult.

But I would recommend using [PortCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/portcmis.html) and the Browser binding instead of DotCMIS.

Comment: I didn't know about PortCMIS